# Angularjs:ng-model binding doesn't work after the first AJAX request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a post request via angularjs.

```
<input class="form-control"  ng-model="hotel.hotel_name" type="text">
 <input class="form-control"  ng-model="hotel.hotel_loc" type="text">
 <input type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit" ng-click="addHotel(hotel)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
```

**controller**

```
$scope.addHotel=function(hotel){
   $http({
          method:"POST",
          data:{'hotel':hotel},
          url:base_url+'operator/hotel/add_hotel'
      }).then(function serverResponse(response){
          //clear the old form data
          $scope.hotel=[];
     })
}
```

Once the data processed successfully clear the old form data `$scope.hotel=[]`

But when i resubmit the form with some values it can't read i will get `undefiend`

```
$scope.addHotel=function(hotel){
   //undefiend
   console.log(hotel);
  }
```

Note:
On the first time post request and response is success ,but can't do after that

Comment: have you defined `hotel` on `scope` object?

Comment: hotel is an object not an array change it to $scope.hotel={}

Comment: @user2181397: the markup in the view does that

Comment: @Paritosh what you mean by _markup in the view does that_

Comment: @user2181397: the `controller` of the view, seeing `ng-model="hotel.hotel_name"` creates `$scope.hotel = { hotel_name: undefined }`. We don't need to define it separately inside `controller` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `hotel` to an `array`. You should set it to `object` instead.

```
$http({
      method:"POST",
      data:{'hotel':hotel},
      url:base_url+'operator/hotel/add_hotel'
  }).then(function serverResponse(response){
      //clear the old form data
      $scope.hotel={};   //this is what you should do
 });
```

Or set it to empty strings.

```
$scope.hotel.hotel_name = '';
$scope.hotel.hotel_loc = '';
```